# Manage OS X partition from Windows

Tags: macos, backup, windows

I have dual boot Mac with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 and Windows 10 installed. If something goes wrong and the Mac is not able to boot, I required a software which will enable me to backup working the bootable OS X partition and restore the OS X exactly to its backup state. To backup and restore the OS X partition I am planning to use Windows 10.

Comment: @Pravin What's your question here? Are you looking for a software recommendation, a set-up example?

Answer (score 4):

Your Mac should have a [recovery partition](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). If, for some reason, your Mac partition becomes unbootable, you can boot into recovery mode (hold down Cmd-R when you hear the startup chime) and follow the on-screen instructions to restore from your latest backup.

If, for some reason, your recovery partition is corrupted or missing altogether, you will end up in Internet Recovery mode instead, which will install a fresh copy of OS X from the internet first.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to view your Mac OS files from Windows, when it's installed via Bootcamp. You won't be able to edit the Mac OS files, but you can view them. I'm not sure if you'd be able to easily restore the entire file system like you could with Time Machine or something like Norton Ghost. You can however backup your files this way.